# Typescript : index signature with numbers `in 1 | 2 | 3`

Tags: typescript

```
type A = {[K in '1' | '2']: string} // ok
type B = {[K in 1 | 2]: string} // error
```

[image]

Is there a decent reason, I didn't find an issue on github, but decided first to ask here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key of js object is string. In javascript it will be converted and proper result will be returned when accessing a key using both string or integer.

```
var a = {1:10};
console.log(a[1]);
console.log(a['1']);
```

But they are checking it strictly. 
Like here

```
parseInt(false);
```

Comment: Ah ok actually.